# An estimate of a sum

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I'm looking for an estimate of this sum $\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\mu^2(n)}{\varphi(n)}$ where $\mu$ is the Möbius function and $\varphi$ the Euler's totient function.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is a post on [math.se] about this sum: [Bounding this arithmetic sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/688857). You can try whether you notice also something else among the search results in [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%5Cleq%20x%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cmu%5E2(n)%7D%7B%5Cvarphi(n)%7D%24&p=1) or [SearchonMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=%24%7B%5Csum_%7Bn%5Cleq%20x%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cmu%5E2%28n%29%7D%7B%5Cvarphi%28n%29%7D%7D%24). (Unfortunately, the latter shows *some* of the results only to subscribers.)

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful.